# Building nodes on computers in a local network

Tags: node

How may I add the public IP address of a relay node to a block producer?
I have set both machines at home so they share the same public IP address if I am not wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The relay node needs to know the IP of the block producer. If they are in the same network, you can use the local IP for this. Only the relay node needs to be accessible from outside of your local network (using your public IP).

When running the nodes at home you also need to make sure that you have a static public IP address or use some sort of DynDNS service. However, DynDNS might cause your nodes to be temporary unavailable which could lead to missing blocks.